# .htaccess project root

Tags: .htaccess

Im working with a lots of project locally. I have set my apache root to refer to my folder containing all of my projects, so `localhost` simply get me there.

Inside subfolders of localhost (wich is root) i would like to add a rewrite rule so `/` refers to the PROJECT root, not localhost.

Example of my structure:

```
localhost/a-very-nice-projekt/
```

Inside the project I want to file link to root like this `src="/img/picture.jpg"`. It would make it easy to move around folders without the need to change links. It also makes it possible to use php include of my navbar and header as links always refers to project root.

Tried a lot of googling and code but I think I'm a little bit wrong...

Comment: ¿What local server are you using? I ask because most of them work with folders the way you describe so you might not need to modify .htaccess, just create folders.

Comment: I'm using Apache! When I look inside my error_log I clearly can see that apache is looking in the wrong folder

[Fri Dec 07 14:17:31 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.12] File does not exist: /Users/Anton/Sites/img, referer: http://192.168.0.12/nyanovium/portfolio.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can really do what you are trying to do, at least through .htaccess. In your case localhost is the domain, and the leading slash in the links tells the browser to grab the resource from that path relative to the domain. Different rules in different folders can't really affect this.

Your best bet is probably to create various virtual hosts on different ports, that would act as separate sites. Create one vhost for each project in your httpd.conf file.

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Path\to\project"
    <Directory "C:\Path\to\project">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, this project would be accessed in your browser as `http://localhost:8081/`. All the paths will work as expected and you should be good to go.

Comment: I will mark this as the final answer as the solution is the correct approach. It's not working for me whoever, but I believe it has something to do with my localhost-config in Mac OSX . If anybody has ideas i'm listening. Will do some googleing on this for Mac OSX...